# Delete user plugin registration tool

Tags: office365, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have register a Service endpoint that add a message on an Azure queue with the image of the `SystemUser` entity; works fine with `Update` message (es: update address or phone) but when i delete the user on Office 365 (and `IsDisabled` is set to True on CRM online) there are no way to trigger the message.
I tryed `Update` message, `SetState`, `SetStateDynamicEntity` but no one is invoked.

Which message I have to set for invoke the service endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I have code that runs to allows or disallows cascading disable events of entities using the "SetStateDynamicEntity".  The only difference I can think of is that The SystemUser entity is slightly different.  I'd try the SetStateDynamicEntity again, and immediately throw an exception to be able to see if it is working or not.  If that still doesn't work, post your screen shot of your registration, and the code in the plugin.

Comment: Did it solve your issue?  If so mark it as the answer

Comment: Hi Daryl, thank you for your answer. There isn't a Plugin code but a Service Endpoint. This Endpoint send a message on a Azure queue that contains an object of type "RemoteExecContextMessage". This Endpoint is correctly invoked when i make update on CRM 2013 OnLine but when i disable an user from Office365 no action is done.